# A hard to find country

Tags: riddle, geography, flags

**I'm a European country, can you find me?**

I share a border with France
I'm bigger than Belgium
I have red in my flag
I'm smaller than Poland
I'm south of Denmark
I have no cross in my flag
I have direct access to the Atlantic ocean
I have a "R" in my name
I'm not Portugal

*And of course, I lied only once.*

Comment: Clarification: the North Sea is not considered to be "direct access to the Atlantic Ocean". I know there might be debates about that, but it was not intended as such.

Comment: Clarification 2: a country is not considered to share a border with itself, to be bigger or smaller than itself or south of itlsef.

Comment: Possible entry for [FTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/fortnightly-topic-challenge-45-flags?cb=1)?

Comment: If you think it's relevant, but this puzzle is not centered on flags, it's just a part of it

Comment: Well, the brief only said puzzles which 'use the flags tag' - and (since I retagged it!) your puzzle certainly qualifies that way. If you feel it doesn't revolve around flags 'enough' then that's fine to keep it entirely separate. Your call :) (Just wanted to point out that was the theme for this fortnight in case you hadn't spotted it...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are:

> **SURINAME** in South America!

*I share a border with France*

> Suriname borders French Guiana, an overseas territory of France.
>  [image]

*I'm bigger than Belgium*
*I have red in my flag*
*I'm smaller than Poland*
*I'm south of Denmark*
*I have no cross in my flag*

> Suriname is bigger than Belgium but smaller than Poland. The flag contains a red central stripe between white and green stripes, with a yellow star (no cross). Being situated only just north of the equator, it is *much* further south than Denmark.
>  [image]

*I have direct access to the Atlantic ocean*
*I have a "R" in my name*
*I'm not Portugal*

> Being on the northern shores of South America, Suriname has direct access to the Atlantic (see the map at the top of this answer again). Its name contains an 'R' and (obviously) it is not Portugal!

So the lie was:

> that you were looking for a **European** country!

Comment: Nice find, being from Europe I never even considered this.

Comment: Well done! The lie was indeed the very first line :D

Comment: Thanks @Keelhaul - a lovely quirk of geography, as its rare to find an rot13(birefrnf greevgbel) with a land border!

Comment: I did consider this but ended up going down the wrong path... good job!

Comment: I have some serious doubts about a country that clearly to the north of a place called "Ecuador" being in the southern hemisphere :-)

Comment: @Bass Oops! That's a silly mistake! Will fix it up, thanks...

Answer (score 7):

You are

> the Netherlands

I share a border with France

> It does, via [the Caribbean island of Saint Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Martin_(island)) - the northern half is part of France and the southern half is part of the Netherlands

I'm bigger than Belgium

> 41,865 sq.km vs Belgium's 30,689 sq.km

I have red in my flag

> [image]

I'm smaller than Poland

> Again, 41,865 sq.km, vs. Poland's 312,696 sq.km

I'm south of Denmark

> Lies between latitudes 50N and 54N, Denmark lies lies further north at 58N and 54 33' N (discounting Greenland)

I have no cross in my flag

> Nope; refer back to the image under "I have red in my flag"

I have access to the Atlantic Ocean

> As per OP's clarifications, this is the lie, as the Netherlands borders the North Sea, not the Atlantic

I have an "R" in my name

> Nethe**r**lands (not Holland! That's only one province!)

I'm not Portugal

> You sure ain't!

Comment: This fits pretty well but rot13(Treznal vf qverpgyl fbhgu bs Qraznex naq nyfb svgf nyy ohg bar pyhr)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't consider the North Sea as the same as the Atlantic ocean, I'll add a clarification

Comment: Realised there's still a way this country could be considered to meet the terms of the puzzle... one moment, please...

Comment: I did not think of Saint Martin, indeed. A bit more of a stretch than the intended answer, but well played nonetheless. If I had a half-checkmark I would award it to you ;)

Comment: Does the Netherlands not have direct access to the Atlantic as soon as you take Saint Martin into account?!

Comment: @Retudin Yeah, that occurred to me shortly after I made the change... never mind!

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about

> France

> Technically this shares borders with France, all borders

The lie would be

> I'm smaller than Poland ->
>  France is bigger than Poland

Comment: But Germany has no access to the Atlantic Ocean ;)

Comment: Sorry, I followed the same reasoning as @F1Krazy's answer

Comment: This is it, isn't it?

Comment: Not either, second clarification

Answer (score 2):

Not as good as the accepted answer, but I thought of

> West Germany
>  The sneaky part is that is is not a country anymore, but only the "I have direct access to the Atlantic ocean" is a lie.

Answer (score 2):

There's also

> The United Kingdom of G**r**eat B**r**itain and No**r**thern I**r**eland

Plenty of "R's. Definitely not Portugal.

Shares a border with France:

> It's a water border, but still a border. And if you don't like that, consider the one in the Chunnel.

Has direct access to the Atlantic Ocean:

> Cornwall, the Hebrides, Orkney, Shetland, and Rockall

Larger than Belgium and smaller than Poland

> Belgium:  30,689 km2.  UK: 244,820. Poland: 312,696.

South of Denmark:

> The southernmost point of Denmark is 54°33´N near Gedser.  The southernmost point of the UK are some rocks off the the Isles of Scilly at 49°51´, unless you count Jersey which is 49°8´

Finally the flag:

> [image: Union Jack]
> Clearly has red in it, and the lie is the lack of a cross.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

> Liberia

The lie being:

> Shares a border with France

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you provide more explanation for how Liberia fits the other clues? As you can see with the other answers, a line-by-line explanation is useful to see how your answer fits.

Comment: Oops, I missed the "I'm a European country"!  Sorry.